# Javascript not detecting Jquery.blockUI.js or Jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have include both scripts on my `@section scripts`

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="/GTracker/Scripts/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/GTracker/Scripts/jQuery.blockUI.js"></script>

    <script src="/GTracker/Scripts/Tree2.js"></script>
}
```

In `Tree2.js` I create the tree using `jstree`. Then same `Tree2.js` have an interval function to check the selected item on the tree or try to block one element to display a waiting cursor and get a message doesnt exits.

I check the `view-source` code and both js are there. Im loading some other partial view, but that should affect this page??

I try putting the `<script>` tag outside the `@section scripts` inside the ` tag, on the layout. And nothing.

[image]

Comment: Where is jQuery ?! Maybe you need to change scripts order (after jQuery) !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Jquery is on the `Layout.cshtml` as I said first time work, then get broken. I think I found the error, is because multiple Jquery declaration but dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Please take a look at [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Not sure if apply to my case. I make another question. I think my problem is on how I declare the script on partial view let me know if that conflict help me with my case . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734014/mvc-how-test-scripts-for-layout-view-partial-view